# How to solve PHP Fatal error: Class 'Eltrino_DiamanteDesk_Helper_Data' not found in /home/abc/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

My Extension code is :

> Path :**app/code/community/Eltrino/DiamanteDesk/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Eltrino LLC (http://eltrino.com)
 *
 * Licensed under the Open Software License (OSL 3.0).
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 *
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@eltrino.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 */

class Eltrino_DiamanteDesk_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    const XML_PATH_DIAMANTE_DESK_API_USERNAME = 'diamantedesk/api/username';
    const XML_PATH_DIAMANTE_DESK_API_KEY = 'diamantedesk/api/key';
    const XML_PATH_DIAMANTE_DESK_API_SERVER_ADDRESS = 'diamantedesk/api/server_address';
    const XML_PATH_DIAMANTE_DESK_BRANCH_CONFIGURATION_BRANCH = 'diamantedesk/branch_configuration/branch';
    const XML_PATH_DIAMANTE_DESK_CONFIGURATION_FOOTER_LINK_URL = 'diamantedesk/configuration/footer_link_url';

    public function getSupportLink()
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig(static::XML_PATH_DIAMANTE_DESK_CONFIGURATION_FOOTER_LINK_URL);
    }
}
```

Extension xml file path : app/etc/modules/Eltrino_DiamanteDesk.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eltrino_DiamanteDesk>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Eltrino_DiamanteDesk>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Note** : Magento return Order Blank Page

How can i solve the issue?

Comment: as per file path you have added, Your file name should be `Data.php` instead of `mage.php`

Comment: @Piyush Its my mistake, Pls check with my updates.

Comment: Please mention how is helper class defined in the config.xml? BTW, the name **data.php** should be **Data.php.**

Comment: @Piyush My order page page return blank page

Comment: can you please add more details? how you are calling this helper and your `config.xml` code

Comment: @Piyush Actually this extension, https://github.com/eltrino/DiamanteDeskMagentoExtension

Comment: @Piyush After uploaded to my root folder, i am getting my order page blank.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora pls check my updates

Comment: @zus, are you getting anything in the log files of Magento?

Comment: Have you tried after disabling the module?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora If i try to disable the  extension , still the error retain.

Comment: Then I don't think that problem is in the extension.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora FYI - Extension is the issue, after disable from back-end now the order open.

Comment: That is what I asked in my comment.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Okay,

Comment: @MohitKumarArora If i disable(False) the extension from code like app/etc/filen_name.xml its not wokring, if i try to disable from backend like System->configuration->Advanced-> Disable, then the issue will solve.